# Request.Form HTML + select multiple box values

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I am trying to get values from a select multiple box like this but the breakpoint at 'For Each Item in box' is nothing, what am I doing wrong? Please advice, thanks:

```
   Dim box = Request.Form("outletToBox")
     For Each item In box
         Dim abc As String = item.ToString
         Dim cdf As String = abc
     Next
```

My Select box:

```
 <select multiple size="8" style="width: 135px" runat="server" onblur="selectAll(this, true, document.getElementById('<%#uilblDestinationQualOutlet.ClientID%>'))"
    id="outletToBox" onclick="return outletToBox_onclick()">
  </select>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this question "c#" when it's clearly *not* C#?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have added the values elsewhere? If so, can you post your code that performs the population?

Answer (score 0):

Actual no `name` parameter is specified in your HTML. That's why is nothing.
And also, if you're using MVC or something else, be careful that the `name` parameter will be given from the webapp itself, so your `Request.Form("mykeyhere")` will be invalid.

So you have two solutions:

- give a proper `name` attribute to your `select` item or,
- use `outletToBox.SelectedItems` where you read your Post data.

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this....

```
for i=0 to Request.form("listbox name").count-1
listboxvalue=Request.form("listbox name").item(i)
 Response.write listboxvalue & "<br>"
next
```

Comment: This question was asked about vb.net, so the for loop actually needs to be for i=0 to Request.form("listbox name").count - 1